# Google Docs ImportXML can't scrape anymore?

Tags: google-sheets, worksheet-function, xpath, importxml

*ImportXML lets you get information from filetypes such as xml, html, csv, tsv, as well as RSS and Atom feeds.*

This [example in Google Docs Help for importXml function](http://support.google.com/docs/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=155184) -

```
=importXml("toysrus.com";; "//a/@href")
```

... fails with this message -

> error: The xPath query given could not be evaluated. Please check the
>   syntax of the query: //a/@href

There are [2 other](https://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/#!categories/docs/importing--exporting/docs/jIBZZ8D4Gvc/overview) [cases](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/23756/in-google-spreadsheets-the-xpath-method-with-google-maps-dont-work-anymore) where they ran well earlier but now fail. The function [scrapes well in this case](http://aspenbio.wordpress.com/2012/01/14/pancreatic-cancer-are-we-making-any-progress/).

Are there any changes in the way ImportXML function works in Google Docs Spreadsheet that makes it fail in some cases?

Comment: Do you still face those problems? Was the answer of @Siva sufficient? Please give us some feedback.

Comment: the reason your syntax didn't work was for a few reasons:   you need to have the protocol in front of the url, i.e. http://, you also need only one comma or semicolon between.

Answer (score 2):

> error: The xPath query given could not be evaluated. Please check the syntax of the query: //a/@href

The Error message says *`XPath could not be evaluated`*.

Here the problem is: you need to provide / target with proper XPath to retrieve the value.

Refer my sample XPath for this:-

> **`=importXml("http://www.toysrus.com", "/html/body/div[@id='hdrWrapper']/div/div/ul/li/a/@href")`**

### UPDATED:

Your requested formula will be as mentioned below:-

```
=ImportXML("http://www.thefreedictionary.com/p/taciturn", "//div[@class='ds-single']")
```

Comment: Thanks, that works but isn't it surprising that the official sample doesn't work

Comment: Thanks, that works but isn't it surprising that the sample in the official docs doesn't work. Has the syntax changed or are their new rules for it to work? How should I frame the query to get the meaning of a word from thefreedictionary.com. This is what I tried =ImportXML("http://thefreedictionary.com/p/taciturn","/html/body/div/table/tbody/tr/td/div/div[@class='ds-single']")

Comment: @mvark: I have updated my answer. Refer it.